# Issue on parsing JSON data in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am working on retrieving result set using postcode using jquery autocomplete. here the code which i am trying to use...but it displays empty set of rows

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Auspost Postcode search</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#postcode").autocomplete({
            minLength:3, //minimum length of characters for type ahead to begin
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'json.php', //your server side script
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        postcode: request.term
                    },

                    success: function (data) {
                        //if multiple results are returned
                        if(data.Addresses instanceof Array)                             
                            response ($.map(data.Addresses, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.Addresses,
                                    value: item.Addresses
                                }
                            }));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="auspost.php" method="post">
 <label for="postcode">Postcode:
     <input name="postcode" id="postcode" type="text">
 </label>
 <input type="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

this is the JSON code result set(response from json.php) which i am receiving through API.

```
{
"Latitude": -0.020223,
"Longitude": 51.504859,
"Addresses": [
 "Abbey Offices Ltd, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
 "B B V A, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
 "B P R Interiors Ltd, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
 "Citihub Ltd, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
 "Coutts & Co, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
]
}
```

Here is my json.php file code:

```
<?php
$postcode = urlencode($_POST['postcode']);
$username = "api-key";
$password = "my-api-key"; // here i will include my api key
$remote_url = 'https://api.getAddress.io/uk/'.$postcode;

// Create a stream
$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
'method'=>"GET",
'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")                 
 )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents($remote_url, false, $context);

 print_r($file);
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, that's not valid JSON (http://jsonlint.org/). Keys must be strings. That's why it cannot be parsed. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example.

Comment: sorry sorry @FelixKling ..thats my mistake i used json parser which is a chrome extension..where i copied the json code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.Addresses` is an array of **strings**. I.e. `item` is a string. Strings don't have an `Addresses` property. Your code should be

```
return {
    label: item,
    value: item
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
{
Latitude: -0.020223,
Longitude: 51.504859,
Addresses: [
 {"Abbey Offices Ltd, 1 Canada Square, LONDON"},
{ "B B V A, 1 Canada Square, LONDON"},
{ "B P R Interiors Ltd, 1 Canada Square, LONDON"},
{ "Citihub Ltd, 1 Canada Square, LONDON"},
{ "Coutts & Co, 1 Canada Square, LONDON"}
]
```

}

Above should be the response from request query.
Use @XMLRootElement before Class Address if your Address is a Bean/Model instance

Comment: You made the invalid JSON even more invalid. `{"Abbey Offices Ltd, 1 Canada Square, LONDON"}` is not valid in JSON nor in JavaScript.

Comment: Ofcourse we can nullify the commas bv creating strings containing comma using blackslash

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "nullify the commas", but the commas are not the problem. `{"..."}` just isn't valid.